# iOS client tries to insert an object with all the fields set to null to Endpoint on localhost

Tags: ios, google-app-engine, nullpointerexception, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-endpoints

I am new to developing iOS client for Google App Engine backend. I encounter an issue where i was able to communicate with the backend but unable to insert a new record into the datastore.

Here is the code for the backend

```
@ApiMethod(name = "insertDCustomerRecord")
public DCustomerRecord insertDCustomerRecord(DCustomerRecord dcustomerrecord) {
    EntityManager mgr = getEntityManager();
    try {
        //Object pass in is JSON format, convert to object instance
        DCustomerRecord newRecord = new DCustomerRecord(dcustomerrecord.getNRIC(), dcustomerrecord.getContactNumber());
        if (containsDCustomerRecord(newRecord)) {
            throw new EntityExistsException("Object already exists");
        }
        mgr.persist(newRecord);
    } finally {
        mgr.close();
    }
    return dcustomerrecord;
}
```

here is the code for the ios client

```
- (void) initView {
    GRGServiceManager* manager = [GRGServiceManager getInstance];
    GTLServiceDcustomerrecordendpoint* service = [manager getDCustomerRecordService];


    GTLDcustomerrecordendpointDCustomerRecord* newRecord = [[GTLDcustomerrecordendpointDCustomerRecord alloc] init];
    [newRecord setNric:@"1234567A"];
    [newRecord setContactNumber:@"12344574"];
    GTLQueryDcustomerrecordendpoint* query = [GTLQueryDcustomerrecordendpoint queryForInsertDCustomerRecordWithObject:newRecord];
    [service executeQuery:query completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket, GTLObject *object, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Inserted new object");
    }];
}
```

Here is the entity class

```
@Entity
public class DCustomerRecord {

    /**
     * @description this is the primary key of the record, it is auto-generated
     */
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Key id;
    public Key getId() {
        return id;
    }

    /**
     * @description this is to store the NRIC of the customer
     */
    private String m_sNRIC;
    public String getNRIC() {
        if(m_sNRIC == null)
            m_sNRIC = "";
        return m_sNRIC;
    }
    public void setNRIC(String nric) {
        m_sNRIC = new String(nric);
    }

    /**
     * @description this is to store the contact number of the customer
     */
    private String m_sContactNumber;
    public String getContactNumber() {
        if(m_sContactNumber == null)
            m_sContactNumber = "";
        return m_sContactNumber;
    }
    public void setContactNumber(String contact) {
        m_sContactNumber = new String(contact);
    }

    /**
     * @description this is to store the number of lucky draw chance this customer has
     */
    private Integer m_nNumberOfLuckyDraw;
    public int getNumberOfLuckyDraw() {
        if(m_nNumberOfLuckyDraw == null)
            m_nNumberOfLuckyDraw = 0;
        return m_nNumberOfLuckyDraw;
    }
    public void setNumberOfLuckyDraw(int newNumber) {
        m_nNumberOfLuckyDraw = new Integer(newNumber);
    }

    /**
     * @description this is to store the number of passcode redemption this customer has made
     */
    private Integer m_nNumberOfPasscodeRedemption;
    public int getNumberOfPasscodeRedemption() {
        if(m_nNumberOfPasscodeRedemption == null)
            m_nNumberOfPasscodeRedemption = 0;
        return m_nNumberOfPasscodeRedemption;
    }
    public void setNumberOfPasscodeRedemption(int newNumber) {
        m_nNumberOfPasscodeRedemption = new Integer(newNumber);
    }

    /**
     * @description this is to store the number of photo taken by this customer
     */
    private Integer m_nNumberOfPhotoTaken;
    public int getNumberOfPhotoTaken() {
        if(m_nNumberOfPhotoTaken == null)
            m_nNumberOfPhotoTaken = 0;
        return m_nNumberOfPhotoTaken;
    }
    public void setNumberOfPhotoTaken(int newNumber) {
        m_nNumberOfPhotoTaken = new Integer(newNumber);
    }

    /**
     * @description this is to store the the time stamp in which the record is created
     */
    private Long m_nDateCreated;
    public long getDateCreated() {
        if(m_nDateCreated == null)
            m_nDateCreated = 0L;
        return m_nDateCreated;
    }
    public void setDateCreated(long date) {
        m_nDateCreated = new Long(date);
    }

    /**
     * @description this is to store the time stamp is which the record last communicate with server
     */
    private Long m_nLastUpdated;
    public long getLastUpdated() {
        if(m_nLastUpdated == null)
            m_nLastUpdated = 0L;
        return m_nLastUpdated;
    }
    public void setLastUpdated(long date) {
        m_nLastUpdated = new Long(date);
    }

    /**
     * @description the default constructor
     * @param nric - NRIC of the customer
     * @param contactNumber - the contact number of the customer
     */
    public DCustomerRecord(String nric, String contactNumber) {
        //Initialization
        setNRIC(nric);
        setContactNumber(contactNumber);
        setNumberOfLuckyDraw(0);
        setNumberOfPasscodeRedemption(0);
        setNumberOfPhotoTaken(0);
        setDateCreated(System.currentTimeMillis());
        setLastUpdated(System.currentTimeMillis());
    }
}
```

The error may or may not help, but this is what is shown in the Eclipse console when i run the iOS app connecting to the local version of the backend server.

```
Aug 16, 2014 7:51:23 PM com.google.api.server.spi.SystemService invokeServiceMethod
INFO: cause={0}
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.datanucleus.api.jpa.JPAEntityManager.find(JPAEntityManager.java:318)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jpa.JPAEntityManager.find(JPAEntityManager.java:256)
    at com.grg.database.record.DCustomerRecordEndpoint.containsDCustomerRecord(DCustomerRecordEndpoint.java:170)
    at com.grg.database.record.DCustomerRecordEndpoint.insertDCustomerRecord(DCustomerRecordEndpoint.java:104)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.invoke(Runtime.java:115)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemService.invokeServiceMethod(SystemService.java:359)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet.execute(SystemServiceServlet.java:160)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet.doPost(SystemServiceServlet.java:118)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:127)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:63)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:125)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:366)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectModuleRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:349)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:116)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:98)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:490)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:938)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:755)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)

Aug 16, 2014 7:51:23 PM com.google.api.server.spi.SystemService invokeServiceMethod
SEVERE: null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.datanucleus.api.jpa.JPAEntityManager.find(JPAEntityManager.java:318)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jpa.JPAEntityManager.find(JPAEntityManager.java:256)
    at com.grg.database.record.DCustomerRecordEndpoint.containsDCustomerRecord(DCustomerRecordEndpoint.java:170)
    at com.grg.database.record.DCustomerRecordEndpoint.insertDCustomerRecord(DCustomerRecordEndpoint.java:104)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.invoke(Runtime.java:115)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemService.invokeServiceMethod(SystemService.java:359)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet.execute(SystemServiceServlet.java:160)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet.doPost(SystemServiceServlet.java:118)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:127)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:63)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:125)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:366)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectModuleRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:349)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:116)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:98)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:490)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:938)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:755)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
```

To my knowledge, the error is caused by the a dcustomerrecord with all fields set to null that is passed into my insertDCustomerRecord in the backend server. I have tried debugging the server and my assumptions seems to be right.

Has anyone encounter this problem before? Can anyone help with this error? I believe i may have left out something important in the code but I am not sure where to begin. I have been Googling this problem for a few days now but with no luck. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I currently see the same problem when connecting to a test server on localhost. Apparently it does not occur when connecting to the same service on Google production servers.

Comment: @Drux: i tried uploading to live servers but when I checked the logs in the developer console, it shows the same error. Thanks for your help anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than wasting time trying debug the problem, I have instead used JSON objects to communicate with the iOS client which works perfectly so far. This is not the first problem with endpoint libraries I have faced while developing for Android and iOS. 1 other problem was the need to edit the endpoint, specifically the insert and contains functions because the auto-generated code took in the wrong argument when communicating with an Android client. Its also a hassle to ensure each servlet has to be defined properly in the Servlet-Path in the xml files since Google App Engine does not support Servlet 3.0.

Until Google make their endpoint library "smarter", I strongly recommend using JSON passing for Google App Engine development.